# How to install driver for unplugged device

Tags: windows-xp

I have .inf file and I have to install driver (in Windows XP) for device that unplugged how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click at inf-file and select install.

[image: Install inf file]

If suddenly inf file has a section [DefaultInstall], you can then install the driver from the command line:

```
rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 128 <driverfile.inf>
```

`128` - tells setup to NOT restart if the inf needs to restart computer.